# ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, svm

I am getting error which is specify "**ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)**"
I just want to get prediction results bu I can not run fit method.(`estimator.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn_train(), steps=10000`) I get the error while trying to run this code. I have 10000 rows and 8 int columns.I dropped string columns for now . `(x_train.shape)` -->(8000, 8).`y_train.shape`--> (8000,).What kind of shape is talking about? I am googling bu I can not find useful things. What shoul I do? What am I missing? All codes below. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tempfile
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_data(data, rate, label):
    data = data.dropna()

    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=rate)

    train_label = train_data[label]
    train_data = train_data.drop(label, 1)

    test_label = test_data[label]
    test_data = test_data.drop(label, 1)
    return train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label


LABEL="Exited"


data = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, header=0)

data.drop("Surname", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("RowNumber", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("CustomerId", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("Geography", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("Gender", axis=1, inplace=True)

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = split_data(data, 0.20, LABEL)



def get_input_fn_train():
        input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=x_train.astype('float64'),
            y=y_train.astype('float32'),
            shuffle=False
        )
        return input_fn

def get_input_fn_test():
        input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=x_test.astype('float64'),
            y=y_test.astype('float32'),
            shuffle=False
        )
        return input_fn


feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input_fn(
                                                       get_input_fn_train())


model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.SVM(
example_id_column=tf.constant(np.arange(len(y_train))),
feature_columns=feature_columns, l2_regularization=10.0,model_dir=model_dir)                                                       

estimator.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn_train(), steps=10000) 
#(I am getting  error this line)


results=estimator.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn_test(), steps=1)


for key in sorted(results):
  print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))


pred=list(estimator.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn_test()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are other problems but one problem you have is that `example_id_column` argument to `SVM` needs to be a string. It is a name of the feature column representing example ids. In your code it is an integer Tensor. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SVM